# Losing references to objects inside containers

Tags: c++, c++11, pass-by-reference

I am struggling to fix a piece of code, even though I believe I know the cause. I did search a lot on Stack Overflow and many people had similar issues (and good answers were provided), but still, I am not sure I understand the problem with my code.

I tried giving a smaller example, but the structure I have is not simple by itself. I hope the following is simple enough.

My objective on the excerpt:

- Have a vector of points.
- Have a vector of segments. (Whose endpoints are reference to points in the vector above)
- Have a vector of events. (That keep a reference to the exhisting segments and points)

```
segment::segment (point &pt1, point&pt2, int i) {
   s = &pt1; e = &pt2; ind = i; // point *s, point *e, int ind
}
event::event (segment &s, point &pt, int tp) {
   seg = &s; type = tp; p = &pt; //segment *seg, int type, point *p
}
void pre_process (int size, std::vector<point>& pts, std::vector<event>& evts,
        std::vector<segment>& segs) {
    float x, y;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++ i) {
        std::cin >> x >> y;
        pts.push_back({x,y});
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        int j = (i+1)%size;
        if (cmpXY(pts[i], pts[j]))
            segs.push_back({pts[i], pts[j], i});
        else
            segs.push_back({pts[j], pts[i], i});
        evts.push_back({segs[i], *segs[i].s, 0});
        evts.push_back({segs[i], *segs[i].e, 1});
        std::cout << 2*i << "\n";
        std::cout << segs[i].s << "\n";       //ALWAYS EQUAl
        std::cout << evts[2*i].seg->s << "\n";
    } // LINE X
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) { //LINE Y
        std::cout << 2*i << "\n";
        std::cout << segs[i].s << "\n";        //DIFFERENT SOMETIMES
        std::cout << evts[2*i].seg->s << "\n";
    }
```

So, the problem is that some of addresses my objects are pointing to change from LINE X to LINE Y. In particular, pts and segs remain the same.

From what I know and from what I understood [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48366849/object-created-in-for-loop-has-same-address) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60254864/creating-pointers-inside-a-for-loop-results-in-pointing-to-same-memory-address) I cannot get the reference to an object on the stack of any function (my for loop, for example). However, I believe the lifetime of the object on the container is the same as the container itself. It makes me believe that all objects I `push_back()` should persist through the function pre_proccess and the function that is calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`push_back` on vector (might) invalidate previous reference/iterator.

it happens in the loop there

```
if (cmpXY(pts[i], pts[j]))
    segs.push_back({pts[i], pts[j], i});
else
    segs.push_back({pts[j], pts[i], i});
evts.push_back({segs[i], *segs[i].s, 0});
```

you have to `reserve` enough place in `segs` to avoid reallocation (or change the logic).

Comment: Interesting. It fixed the issue for my test set. I am trying to understand why at this moment. If I had first built segs, would the problem persist?  I never came upon this problem.

Comment: `std::vector` is contiguous container. Once capacity is reached, it has to reallocate, and move previous value in the new buffer, invalidating every reference to old buffer. Once built (or reserved), you no longer invalidate reference/iterator.

Answer (score 1):

It looks that the vector resize itself and had to be relocated (which will invalidate all iterator references).

Try to use `std::vector::reserve` before processing:

```
void pre_process (int size, std::vector<point>& pts, std::vector<event>& evts,
        std::vector<segment>& segs) {
    pts.reserve(size);
    evts.reserve(size);
    segs.reserve(size);

    float x, y;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++ i) {
        std::cin >> x >> y;
        pts.push_back({x,y});
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        int j = (i+1)%size;
        if (cmpXY(pts[i], pts[j]))
            segs.push_back({pts[i], pts[j], i});
        else
            segs.push_back({pts[j], pts[i], i});
        evts.push_back({segs[i], *segs[i].s, 0});
        evts.push_back({segs[i], *segs[i].e, 1});
        std::cout << 2*i << "\n";
        std::cout << segs[i].s << "\n";       //ALWAYS EQUAl
        std::cout << evts[2*i].seg->s << "\n";
    } // LINE X
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) { //LINE Y
        std::cout << 2*i << "\n";
        std::cout << segs[i].s << "\n";        //DIFFERENT SOMETIMES
        std::cout << evts[2*i].seg->s << "\n";
}
```